# ActiveRecord object attribute name same as method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to call a method on an ActiveRecord object where there is an attribute of the same name. This results in a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` error.

How can I access the object attribute from within the method in order to modify it?

```
def first_name

 return self.first_name.upper

end
```

Comment: You could probably also do `super.upper`

Answer (score 39):

If this is an Active Record model you can use `read_attribute` method

```
def first_name
  read_attribute(:first_name).upper
end
```

Comment: or `self[:first_name].upper` if rubocop complains :)